# Unable to change the default HTTP protocol handler on Windows to a custom command

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, windows-registry, windows-server-2012-r2

If I create a new registry key, for example:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\something\shell\open\command
```

On the Windows command prompt I can now type:

```
start something://....
```

And it will run my command.

However if I edit the current `http` key at:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command
```

And then type:

```
start http://....
```

It will open Chrome no matter what I put as `command` in the above registry location.

Why does the `something` key work, but `http` does not?

How do I redirect the `http` handler to my own command instead of Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here:
https://newoldthing.wordpress.com/2007/03/23/how-does-your-browsers-know-that-its-not-the-default-browser/

Basically the URL handling was changed since Vista, which adds an additional registry redirection. For Chrome and HTTP the command is now located here instead:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\Shell\open\command
```